# Deploy elastic beanstalk application to several regions

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Is it possible to deploy elastic beanstalk application to several regions? 
Is there a way to change eb config to deploy 2 applications at once when you do `eb deploy`?

I need to deploy the same code to us-west and us-east regions.

Comment: http://blog.mikebabineau.com/2013/08/21/multi-region-gotcha-on-elastic-beanstalk/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was easy:

`eb deploy -r us-east-1`

Done! :)